# MYSQL INNER JOIN FUNCTION ERROR Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking to insert values from one table into another.

I have approx 15,000 records so I am concerned about the time it will take for the query to run and insert the relevant records into the new table. To reduce the amount of data it queries, I am trying to include an INNER JOIN function limiting it to a subset of data however am having a lot of trouble.

A cut down version of the query on the whole table looks like:

```
INSERT INTO logic (formId, A1Logic, date) 
SELECT formId, JSON_OBJECT("logic1",JSON_ARRAY(L1A,L1B,L1C)), "'+date+'"
FROM preferences 
WHERE L1A NOT LIKE "%Select question title%" AND L1A <> ""
```

When including an inner join, I thought it would look like the following, however I am receiving an error: **Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column**

```
INSERT INTO logic (formId, A1Logic, date)
SELECT a.formId, JSON_OBJECT("logic1",JSON_ARRAY(a.L1A,a.L1B,a.L1C)), "'+date+'" 
FROM preferences a
INNER JOIN (SELECT formId, L1A, L1B, L1C, MAX(entryID) AS MaxEntryId FROM preferences GROUP BY formId) b 
ON a.formId = b.formId AND a.entryID = b.MaxEntryId 
WHERE L1A NOT LIKE "%Select question title%" AND L1A <> “"
```

Comment: if `formId` is your primary key you can limit your number of records using formID < 'your_id' in where clause

Comment: Please read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5-fill.7/en/group-by-handling.html particularly the bits relating to only_full_group_by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sub query is your problem.

- `SELECT formId, L1A, L1B, L1C, MAX(entryID) AS MaxEntryId FROM preferences GROUP BY formId`

As per your own error message, every field mentioned in the `SELECT` must either be in an aggregate function *(Such as where you use `MAX()`)*, or be mentioned in the `GROUP BY`.

- `L1A, L1B, L1C` are not in aggregates or in the `GROUP BY`

You need something like one of the following:

1. `SELECT formId, L1A, L1B, L1C, MAX(entryID) AS MaxEntryId FROM preferences GROUP BY formId`***`, L1A, L1B, L1C`***
2. `SELECT formId,`***`MAX(L1A) AS L1A, MAX(L1B) AS L1B, MAX(L1C) AS L1C`***`, MAX(entryID) AS MaxEntryId FROM preferences GROUP BY formId`

Exactly what you need is impossible to tell as you've told us nothing about the table `preferences` and/or what your sub query is meant to be doing.

Comment: Thank you MatBailie. Much appreciated.